# sails.js setup: How to make a node module available across the sails project (controller / model, etc)?

Tags: sails.js, node-modules

I just getting started with SailsJS as my first web framework on Node. Let's say I wanna add MomentJS in and use across the app. How to set it up?

Answer (score 16):

you can use the bootstrap.js (in config/)

like:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
  sails.moment = require('moment');

cb();
};
```

in all Sails-Files you can use

```
sails.moment()
```

now.

Comment: don't forget to run ```npm install moment --save```

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to include your node_modules into the client side, such as jQuery, AngularJS or one of the various many font libraries, then you can `npm install` them as normal, but just to be sure in sails you edit your `tasks/config/copy.js` and add a new block, example:

```
grunt.config.set('copy', {
    dev: {
        files: [{
            expand:true,
            cwd: './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts',
            src: ['**/*'],
            dest: '.tmp/public/fonts'
        }
    }
});
```

LESS can be `@import`ed like normal without being copied around. Other assets will need to be copied as above. If you're using the `sails linker` then don't forget to add your JS paths to `tasks/pipeline.js` too (if necessary).

You can read more here:
http://ash.zi.vc/sails/2016/02/02/including-client-side-node-modules-in-my-sails-application/

It's not directly obvious how to sync npm modules to the web accessible directories.

Answer (score 3):

SailsJS is no different to any other NodeJS app. So on top of your (say) Controller.js file, you do

```
var m = require("moment");
```

And you're good to go. @mdunisch's method will obviously let you use the moment package throughout your app, without having to do "require" in each file.